# Print variable with traling newline in R

Tags: r

I want to write the output of multiple `summary()` with a separating `\n`.

```
df = data(cars)

for (col in c('speed', 'dist')) {

    print(
        cat(
            '\n',
            summary(df[col])
        )
    )
}
```

But the output is just

```
 1 character characterNULL

 1 character characterNULL
```

But what I expect is

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0 

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00   26.00   36.00   42.98   56.00  120.00
```

Comment: the data function does not return data, instead `data(car)` will attach the car data set to the global environment. If you run `df = data(cars)`, then `df` will you be the string `"cars"`

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing wrong with the print but with how the `cars` dataset is loaded.

`data()` doesn't return an object but just creates the `cars` object.

The code works when modifying the first line into

```
data(cars)
df = cars
```